# how to mask an unwanted "Dead Store" warning in XCode?

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios, xcode4

How to mask an unwanted "Dead Store" warning in XCode?  That is I have this code for which I don't think it's an issue, so if this is the case I don't want to keep seeing the warning...(welcome for feedback however)

Code is here:

```
// Position and Size Labels in Cell
CGFloat currVertPos = 0; // Maintain lowest position, i.e. starting vertical point for next cell

// Set Position & Get back next veritical position to use
currVertPos = [self resizeLabel:_mainLabel atVertPos:currVertPos];
    currVertPos = [self resizeLabel:_mainLabel2 atVertPos:currVertPos];
    currVertPos = [self resizeLabel:_mainLabel3 atVertPos:currVertPos];
currVertPos = [self resizeLabel:self.secondLabel atVertPos:currVertPos];  // WARNING OCCURS HERE
```

Warning Detail = Value stored "currVertPos" at is never read.

So it's true that for the last line the "currVertPos" isn't needed, but does it really matter, and if not how can I silence the warning?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, the warning doesn't matter; you can eliminate it simply by not doing the store. Delete the `currVertPos =` from the last line and there will be nothing to warn you about.

Answer (score 7):

One other alternative is to use:

```
#pragma unused(currVertPos)
```

[Source: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/194666/is-there-a-way-to-suppress-warnings-in-xcode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/194666/is-there-a-way-to-suppress-warnings-in-xcode)

Comment: This worked for me when the compiler got confused because the variables were used in an if statement.                       #pragma unused(showHideButtonX)
#pragma unused(showHideButtonY)

if ( DISPLAY_SHOWHIDE_BUTTON ) {
            CGRect showHideFrame = CGRectMake(showHideButtonX, showHideButtonY, buttonsSize, buttonsSize);