# How to suppress the "dead store" compiler warning on Xcode?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa, compiler-warnings, pragma

How can I suppress the "dead store" warning on a single file in Xcode?

I tried

```
#pragma clang diagnostic push
#pragma clang diagnostic ignored "-Wunused-value"
```

without luck. Any suggestions?

BTW, I don't want to "fix" the code, because I'm creating a bunch of objects only for the sake of inserting them into a Core Data database. I don't want to do anything else with them at the moment.

Comment: just tell me, what is the "dead store"?

Comment: Why are you trying to suppress a dead store warning? Why not just fix it?

Comment: @0x7fffffff I'm creating a bunch of object only for the sake of inserting them into a Core Data database. I don't want to do anything else with them at the moment.

Comment: The second answer here should help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5294761/how-to-mask-an-unwanted-dead-store-warning-in-xcode

Comment: @atomk: “Second” is relative to sort order. You may want to post an answer here that quotes and links to the specific answer you're referring to.

Answer (score 1):

Although it doesn't work for the whole file, you can silence individual warnings for dead stores by adding

```
(void)variable;
```

after the line causing the warning