# how to get rid of "In class initializer for static data member ... is a C++0x extension" warning in Xcode 4

Tags: c++, xcode, xcode4, c++11

I can get rid of the warnings in the build log by adding -std=c++0x to "other c++ flags", but they still show up in the side pane.  I'm guessing that the other flags are not being passed to clang or whatever is responsible for parsing code for the gui...

Any ideas?

Update:

The warnings have mostly disappeared, but I'm not sure why.  And every time I think they're gone, I get a few again.  I suspect that forcing a build of every project in the workspace has some effect, but I'm really at a loss.

In any case, modifying "other c++ flags" does seem to affect the GUI warnings, contrary to my assumption when I asked this question.  But it takes time.  Ahh, Xcode.

Comment: what are the warnings? what happens if you compile out side of xcode?

Comment: sorry, the warning is in the title.  I haven't tried compiling "outside" of xcode (I assume you mean from the command line); the warnings don't appear in the actual build, only the gui.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a pragma instead of a command line switch, as described in the answer to ["Is there a way to suppress warnings in Xcode?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/194666/is-there-a-way-to-suppress-warnings-in-xcode)

Comment: I haven't actually been able to verify that this is more or less of a solution than adding command line switches, as I can't reliably reproduce the problem..  but it's an excellent suggestion that I didn't know about!  thanks!