# Unused variable 'record' warning

Tags: objective-c

How would I suppress the warning in this code snippet?

```
for (NSDictionary *record in self.records) {
    [deletedRows addObject:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:row inSection:RecordSection]];
    row++;
}
```

Comment: #pragma GCC diagnostic ignored "-Wwarning-flag" suppresses warnings http://stackoverflow.com/questions/194666/is-there-a-way-to-suppress-warnings-in-xcode

Comment: You can use __unused like __unused NSDictionary *record

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use *fast enumeration* at all:

```
for (NSUInteger row = 0; row < [self.records count]; row++) {
    [deletedRows addObject:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:row inSection:RecordSection]];
}
```

This is:

1. Faster, as you are not accessing the array, just generating a sequence of numbers.
2. Cleaner, as there are no annoying compiler directives.
3. Correct, as you don't declare a variable you don't use.

Comment: Cool. That seems to be what I should be doing. Thanks.

Comment: 1. Faster <- Its a joke?

Comment: @OlegSobolev Well I haven't measured it, but I would expect it to be slightly faster.

Comment: LOL. That's true. I thought fast enumeration should be faster? :D

Comment: Look at results of any test, fast enumeration most fast. Specially, if you create variable in for() loop, like in your example! And you call [count:] method each time! Please, never do like that if you need speed. @trojanfoe

Comment: @OlegSobolev The `for` loop in my example doesn't enumerate anything (notice I am not accessing the array using `objectAtIndex:`).  I would therefore expect it to be faster still.

Comment: Here's a good article with benchmarks - http://iosdevelopertips.com/objective-c/high-performance-collection-looping-objective-c.html

Comment: In for(0..1000) loop, you will 1000 times init variable of int type, and 1000 times call count: method. That is not fast.

Comment: @OlegSobolev It would need to be measured to be sure, but I am not going to do that.

Comment: $ For loop: 0.115235
$ Optimized for loop: 0.083858
$ For…in loop: 0.00683898 @trojanfoe

Comment: @OlegSobolev Please put your code on a github gist, so I can see it.

Comment: Look at the link above. @trojanfoe

Comment: So basically, stick to for in but use `__unused`.

Comment: The code in the link is **accessing the array**; where as the code I provide **does not**.  Therefore it's not a valid test.  If you are really interested in knowing if it's faster then you need to measure the code in the question with the code in my answer, which that page does not do.

Comment: @CalvinCheng If you want to make it quicker still (if that's important to you) then initialise the "end index" before the `for` loop, e.g.: `const NSUInteger count = [self.records count]; for (NSUInteger row = 0; row < count; row++) { ... }`.