# Filter the warning type in Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, warnings

In my `project` in `Xcode`, my code always has many `warning`, and I think some is import and some is not that import for my `code`:

Such as a type is :`xxx is deprecaetd in iOS 8.0 - Use xxx`

another type is: `Undeclared selector 'respondsToTapLike'`

or other more.

There is so many type warning:

> [image: many type in proj]

Now, how can I filter the `warning type` in `Buildtime`?

`eg`: I just want to show the type of `Method possibly missing a [super awakeFromNib] call`.

If can filter the type, how to do?

Comment: Please check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/194666/is-there-a-way-to-suppress-warnings-in-xcode

Comment: @Poles, I do not mean to do not display the `warning`, I just want to show the `warning` which type I want.

Comment: use custom warning -  `#warning your custom warning message` before the actual warnings.

Comment: @Poles pole.i mean to show one type of the proj*s types which i want.

Comment: I don't think xcode warning can be filtered that way.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

xcode already have this.up there is 'By Type',down there is keywords filter, is that what you want?
[image: picture]