# Is it correct to suppress warnings if there is an alternative to it in Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, deprecated

I have used AlertView in my project. Since it is deprecated now it shows warnings. If I suppress these warnings without clearing it (by using AlertController) will it affect my project later.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a way to suppress warnings in Xcode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/194666/is-there-a-way-to-suppress-warnings-in-xcode)

Comment: Thanks for your reply but I wanted to know whether my project gets affected if I suppress the warning.@Plo_Koon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

no it won't affect your projcet for the moment, but since they are deprecated, AlertView in the future may be deleted by swift, and then you will have serious problems, so better change them while you are in time. :)