# How Do I fix unused variable 'uploadTask' StorageService.m

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

How Do I fix

```
FIRStorageUploadTask *uploadTask = [uploadRef putData:data metadata:metadata completion:^(FIRStorageMetadata * Nullable
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Just remove `FIRStorageUploadTask *uploadTask =`  and keep

```
[uploadRef putData:data metadata:metadata
```

Also use `@discardableResult` if it again throws warning of unused result

### OR

If you want to particularly suppress a warning you can check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25700438/468724