# How to make POST request to a web server with C++ and Core Foundation APIs for macOS?

Tags: c++, macos, http, core-foundation

I'm trying to follow [this example](https://kolinsturt.github.io/lessons/2012/01/01/post-request-with-headers) to let me make a POST request to a web server and receive its response in pure C++ using Core Foundation functions. I'll copy and paste it here:

```
void PostRequest()
{
    // Create the POST request payload.
    CFStringRef payloadString = CFStringCreateWithFormat(kCFAllocatorDefault, NULL, CFSTR("{\"test-data-key\" : \"test-data-value\"}"));
    CFDataRef payloadData = CFStringCreateExternalRepresentation(kCFAllocatorDefault, payloadString, kCFStringEncodingUTF8, 0);
    CFRelease(payloadString);
    
    //create request
    CFURLRef theURL = CFURLCreateWithString(kCFAllocatorDefault, CFSTR("https://httpbin.org/post"), NULL); //https://httpbin.org/post returns post data
    CFHTTPMessageRef request = CFHTTPMessageCreateRequest(kCFAllocatorDefault, CFSTR("POST"), theURL, kCFHTTPVersion1_1);
    CFHTTPMessageSetBody(request, payloadData);
    
    //add some headers
    CFStringRef hostString = CFURLCopyHostName(theURL);
    CFHTTPMessageSetHeaderFieldValue(request, CFSTR("HOST"), hostString);
    CFRelease(hostString);
    CFRelease(theURL);
    
    if (payloadData)
    {
        CFStringRef lengthString = CFStringCreateWithFormat(kCFAllocatorDefault, NULL, CFSTR("%ld"), CFDataGetLength(payloadData));
        CFHTTPMessageSetHeaderFieldValue(request, CFSTR("Content-Length"), lengthString);
        CFRelease(lengthString);
    }
    
    
    CFHTTPMessageSetHeaderFieldValue(request, CFSTR("Content-Type"), CFSTR("charset=utf-8"));
    
    //create read stream for response
    CFReadStreamRef requestStream = CFReadStreamCreateForHTTPRequest(kCFAllocatorDefault, request);
    CFRelease(request);
    
    //set up on separate runloop (with own thread) to avoid blocking the UI
    CFReadStreamScheduleWithRunLoop(requestStream, CFRunLoopGetCurrent(), kCFRunLoopCommonModes);
    CFOptionFlags optionFlags = (kCFStreamEventHasBytesAvailable | kCFStreamEventErrorOccurred | kCFStreamEventEndEncountered);
    CFStreamClientContext clientContext = {0, (void *)payloadData, RetainSocketStreamHandle, ReleaseSocketStreamHandle, NULL};
    CFReadStreamSetClient(requestStream, optionFlags, ReadStreamCallBack, &clientContext);
    
    //start request
    CFReadStreamOpen(requestStream);
    
    if (payloadData)
        {
        CFRelease(payloadData);
        }
}
```

And the callback:

```
void LogData(CFDataRef responseData)
{
    CFIndex dataLength = CFDataGetLength(responseData);
    UInt8 *bytes = (UInt8 *)malloc(dataLength);
    CFDataGetBytes(responseData, CFRangeMake(0, CFDataGetLength(responseData)), bytes);
    CFStringRef responseString = CFStringCreateWithBytes(kCFAllocatorDefault, bytes, dataLength, kCFStringEncodingUTF8, TRUE);
    CFShow(responseString);
    CFRelease(responseString);
    free(bytes);
}

static void ReadStreamCallBack(CFReadStreamRef readStream, CFStreamEventType type, void *clientCallBackInfo)
{
    CFDataRef passedInData = (CFDataRef)(clientCallBackInfo);
    CFShow(CFSTR("Passed In Data:"));
    LogData(passedInData);
    
    //append data as we receive it
    CFMutableDataRef responseBytes = CFDataCreateMutable(kCFAllocatorDefault, 0);
    CFIndex numberOfBytesRead = 0;
    do
    {
        UInt8 buf[1024];
        numberOfBytesRead = CFReadStreamRead(readStream, buf, sizeof(buf));
        if (numberOfBytesRead > 0)
        {
            CFDataAppendBytes(responseBytes, buf, numberOfBytesRead);
        }
    } while (numberOfBytesRead > 0);
    
    //once all data is appended, package it all together - create a response from the response headers, and add the data received.
    //note: just having the data received is not enough, you need to finish the response by retrieving the response headers here...
    CFHTTPMessageRef response = (CFHTTPMessageRef)CFReadStreamCopyProperty(readStream, kCFStreamPropertyHTTPResponseHeader);
    
    if (responseBytes)
    {
        if (response)
        {
            CFHTTPMessageSetBody(response, responseBytes);
        }
        CFRelease(responseBytes);
    }
    
    
    //close and cleanup
    CFReadStreamClose(readStream);
    CFReadStreamUnscheduleFromRunLoop(readStream, CFRunLoopGetCurrent(), kCFRunLoopCommonModes);
    CFRelease(readStream);
    
    //just keep the response body and release requests
    CFDataRef responseBodyData = CFHTTPMessageCopyBody(response);
    if (response)
    {
        CFRelease(response);
    }
    
    //get the response as a string
    if (responseBodyData)
    {
        CFShow(CFSTR("\nResponse Data:"));
        LogData(responseBodyData);
        CFRelease(responseBodyData);
    }
}
```

I understood how it works, and started implementing it ..... only to get this error:

> 'CFReadStreamCreateForHTTPRequest' is deprecated: first deprecated in
> macOS 10.11 - Use NSURLSession API for http requests

There's absolutely zero examples how to use `NSURLSession` for C++, or how to bypass that idiotic "is deprecated" error.

Any help on how am I supposed to code this in C++ now?

PS. I don't want to use any third-party libraries. This is a simple task that was available with simple API calls (as I showed above.)

PS2. Sorry I am not an Apple developer, and I'm not used to features being deprecated on the whim.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 3 options.

1. Ignore the warning.
2. Use [ObjC runtme](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/objectivec/objective-c_runtime).
3. Use [libcurl](https://curl.se/libcurl/)

The first one is the easiest and the second one is the hardest solutions for your skills. The third option is easy and the most advanced solution - if you extend you software with new features, `CFNetwork` will lack of functionality.

Comment: I set my project to treat warnings as errors. Is there a way to ignore it for that specific function?

Comment: Oh wow, it is possible like in VS. Found it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25700438/843732). In my case I needed to enclose `CFReadStreamCreateForHTTPRequest` in `#pragma GCC diagnostic push` then `#pragma GCC diagnostic ignored "-Wdeprecated-declarations"` followed by `#pragma GCC diagnostic pop`